# ASP.net JQUERY how to sum to label.val()

Tags: jquery, asp.net

**Markup**:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelProfit" runat="server"></asp:Label><p>
<asp:Label ID="LabelCost" runat="server"></asp:Label><p>
<asp:Label ID="LabelFinalBalance" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

I have 3 label LabelProfit and LabelCost get their values from code behind with this method:

**Serverside**:

```
 public void getProfitSum()
 {
     string connectionString = cs.getConnection();
     using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
           myConnection.Open();
           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spSumProfit", myConnection);
           command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", cui.getCurrentId());
           LabelProfit.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
       }
  }
```

I want with Jquery to do 
labelFinalBalance = LabelProfit-LabelCost
Could do that with Jquery?

Comment: Does LabelCost have a value?  -- you do understand the difference between C# server side and JavaScript client side?

Comment: `$("#LabelFinalBalance").text($("#LabelProfit").text() - $("#LabelCost").text());`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var P = $('#<%=LabelProfit.ClientID%>').html();
var C = $('#<%=LabelCost.ClientID%>').html();

$('#<%=LabelFinalBalance.ClientID%>').html(parseInt(P) - parseInt(C));
```

Comment: how to change "NaN" on LabelFinalBalance if on of other labels is without value

Comment: <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
      
        var P = $('#<%=LabelProfit.ClientID%>').html();
        var C = $('#<%=LabelCost.ClientID%>').html();

        if (P == null || C == null) {
            $('#<%=LabelFinalBalance.ClientID%>').html(0)

        } else {

            $('#<%=LabelFinalBalance.ClientID%>').html(parseInt(P) - parseInt(C));
        }
    });
</script> but nothing change

Comment: For `var P = $('#<%=LabelProfit.ClientID%>').html();` what value you are getting for `P`, if it is empty??

Comment: OK, just do one thing, just replace `if (P == null || C == null)` with this `if ((P == null || P == '') || (C == null || C == ''))` and everything will work fine...